# Copy picture to user's gallery

Tags: codenameone

I'm making an app where the user can take pictures and export them to a database.

After the user exports the pictures, he can delete them or save them to his gallery.

I'm stuck at the point of copying the pictures to the gallery, I don't know how to access to it and if it is even possible.

The pictures are stored like so (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41208739/9987888) :

```
OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(pathToBeStored);
ImageIO.getImageIO().save(img, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, 0.9f);
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently have an API that consistently places images in the gallery. It might be something worth adding to [Camera Kit](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/camerakit-low-level-camera-api.html) via native code.